# pgfplot fails to plot complex function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I'm trying to plot the function `sin(pi*x)*sinh(pi-pi*y)/sinh(pi)` using pgfplots. This is the code I have so far

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor} % use color

\usepackage{tikz} % Required for drawing custom shapes
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots, plotmarks, calc, spy, pgfplots.polar}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks, calc, spy, pgfplots.polar}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            width=8cm,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        xmin=0,xmax=1,
        ymin=0,ymax=1,
    ]
    % use TeX as calculator:
    \addplot3[surf,domain=0:1, samples=20] { sin(pi*x)*sinh(pi-pi*y)/sinh(pi)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces
[image]

but I am expecting this function (plotted in Mathematica):

[image]

so I'm curious to know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that the problem is that pgfplot assumes that the arguments of `sin` is in degrees, which `Mathematica` does not. In fact

```
 \documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
 \usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor} % use color

 \usepackage{tikz} % Required for drawing custom shapes
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}
 \usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
 \usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots, plotmarks, calc, spy, pgfplots.polar}
 \usetikzlibrary{plotmarks, calc, spy, pgfplots.polar}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}[
             width=8cm,
         xlabel=$x$,
         ylabel=$y$,
         xmin=0,xmax=1,
         ymin=0,ymax=1,
     ]
     % use TeX as calculator:
     \addplot3[surf,domain=0:1, samples=20] { sin(180*x)*sinh(pi-pi*y)/sinh(pi)};
     \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

produces something very reminiscent of your `Mathematica` plot:

[image]

EDIT: in a previous version, I also replace the pi of the argument of the sinh in the denominator, which changed the normalization of the plot. (Yes, it is really odd that pgfplots assumes the arguments of `sin` but not `sinh` to be degrees.)

Comment: The maximum z value should be 1, so the shape is good, but you forgot to scale one of the arguments as `sin(180*x)*sinh(180*(1-y))/sinh(180)};`. Still with this function I can't get it right

Comment: @aaragon Yes, I noticed that also and edited my answer. Sorry for this. (Probably both of us agree that this behavior of pgfplots is odd.)

Comment: is it really odd that pgfplots does _not_ assume arguments of hyperbolic sine to be in degrees?? (the opposite wouldn't make mathematical sense). What _is odd_ is that it assumes the argument of trigonometric sine is in degrees and not in radians! Ah wait, you actually say something like that, it seems.

Comment: @jfbu probably there is some wording issue. Anyway, I completely agree with what you are saying. More precisely, the most reasonable option is to have radians for both. If both have arguments in degrees, this is weird but not as odd as the current situation. Of course, it could be worse if it would expect degrees on Mondays and radians on all other days of the week ;-)